# AngularJS: Render HTML output to a string

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, pdf, render-to-string

I am writing an app that must generate a PDF file based on the HTML generated by AngularJS.  I do not want to display this output to the user.  I want to capture the rendered HTML to a string and send it to a server, where a service there will receive the HTML source and create the PDF file.

I understand that one way to grab rendered HTML is through accessing the element's innerHTML property after compiling it in a directive.  But how can I be certain that there are no further digests that need to take place?  Also, can this method work without writing the results to the DOM?  -- Or, at least, without displaying the results to the user?  Thanks!

Comment: You could generate all the html you want in a hidden element that user never sees. Be curious to see how pdf library handles non standard tags and attributes used in angular markup.

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks, that's part of my question.  The bigger question is how do I determine that the digest cycle has run it's final iteration.

Comment: not sure what context of that question is. If in directive can use `$timeout` to run code and digest is done when it fires

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for both comments.  Together they provide the answer to my question.  If you want to submit them as an answer, I'll select it to increase your rating.

Comment: Just wondering if you can share the solution to this, need to do the same thing.